# How can I extract the className from a span that is selected using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this HTML:

```
<span class="redColor">gold</span>
```

And when I have the text selected that is within the span tags, I need to be able to somehow extract the className from the span using javascript. I don't know anything about the class in advance, only that it will be in a span, and the text will be selected.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean Text selected with the mouse or the keyboard? You can access that with

```
window.getSelection()
```

Then you can work your way up the DOM tree:

```
window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode.className
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection.anchorNode for documentation of the Selection class

Answer (score 0):

Use `className` property.

Example:

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
document.write("Body CSS class: " + x.className);
```

Comment: `x` is a NodeList, it doesn't have the `className` property.

Comment: But how do I know which one is selected? I only need the classname for the span that is currently selected.

Comment: @Lizza - What do you mean by "selected"?

Comment: The text is selected, or highlighted. I know there is a document.getSelection() function that is what I need, but I am not sure where to go from there.